# Genymotion 2.8.1 - Can't flash Play Services on any Virtual Device

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-services, genymotion

So, on Genymotion 2.8.1, I've tried flashing Play Services on a number of Virtual Devices. None works. I get the error along the lines of "Flashing xyz zip failed for an unknown reason, check the logcat for more info"

In the logcat, I move to where the error starts, and there's NO error message giving info as to what is happening, except something like 'Flashing stopped'

I've downloaded about 4 different virtual devices of different OS versions, and I'm beginning to suspect Genymotion 2.8.1 has a problem.

Any idea how to use or flash Play Services onto Genymotion 2.8.1 or any alternative means to install apps from Play Store?

Answer (score 0):

You can use old vision.  v2.5.4 is usable.

http://azodl.blogspot.tw/2015/06/genymotion.html